# NSCoding for Parse PFObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nscoding

I'm attempting to use this library https://github.com/updatezen/Parse-NSCoding/ in my project, but when I import the .h/.m files into my project it still throws a warning when I try to do cache my PFObjects `[cache setObject:myPFObject forKey:@"PFObjectID"];` saying

```
"Sending 'PFObject *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id <\NSCoding>'"
```

Has anybody else tried to use this library with any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of this library. It was intended to be used with `PFObject` subclasses. It looks like the cache you're using is expecting a type that explicitly implements `NSCoding`. Try subclassing `PFObject` in a new class and adding the `NSCoding` protocol declaration to your .h file.

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS

Comment: The error you are getting is only a compiler warning. Your PFObject will implement NSCoding at runtime. Here is a quick proof:

`PFObject* parseObject = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Test"];
assert([parseObject respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithCoder:)]);
`

Comment: would you mind taking a look at a new question of mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119739/saving-pfobject-nscoding, thanks so much!